# jQuery plugin chainability

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a jQuery plugin, the main aim is to take a select element and create a new component based on it, so far I just want to replace the select with an empty div:

```
(function($){
    $.fancySelect = {version:'1.0'};
    var methods = {
        init: function(options){
            return this.each(function(){                
                var div = $('<div></div>');
                $(this).replaceWith(div);
            });
        }
    };
    $.fn.fancySelect = function(method){
        if (methods[method]){//call a method
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else {
             return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Trying to test, I make a simple select:

```
<select id="sss"></select>
```

When I call:

```
$('#sss').fancySelect();
```

The select is correctly replaced with an empty Div, this is Ok.
But now, when testing chainability, I try:

```
$('#sss').fancySelect().append('<span>new text</span>');
```

But my new div remain empty
So I tried:

```
console.log($('#sss').fancySelect());
```

On firebug I get:

```
[select#sss]
```

Means the plugin is returning the old select.

I tried to add

```
return $(this);
```

after

```
$(this).replaceWith(div);
```

in my plugin code, but nothing changed!


Can you please tell me what I should do to make my plugin return the fresh created Div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return [`this.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), you are returning the original jQuery selection, which hasn't changed even though you've replaced those elements.  Instead of using `each`, use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to adjust what is returned:

```
return this.map(function(){                
    var div = $('<div></div>');
    $(this).replaceWith(div);
    return div;
});
```

Comment: See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xTwCW/) for an alternative implementation. What you've done with map is cleaner though. +1

Comment: @MichaelMior your solution works, but I prefer bdukes one. I came accross similar solutions while testing but I was looking for a **proper** way to do it.

Comment: @skafandri I wouldn't say my solution was improper. I think it's perfectly acceptable. The solution above is essentially doing the same thing. I agree it is cleaner though and his solution is preferred.

Comment: is not improper! but the solution above is way better (especially for readability), the example I gave is just to show my issue, actually my plugin is some thousands of lines of code, so I prefer a "nice looking" solution, FYI: this is what I'm achieving: http://ilyeskooli.com/desktop/